Complete characterization of short exact sequences between finitely generated abelian groups
Let $\textrm{SES}(A, B, C)$ be a relation on the set of isomorphism classes of finitely generated abelian groups, indicating that they fit into a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$. I would like an algorithm that, given one or two of the groups, decides whether the possibilities of the rest are finite, and if so lists all of them.
If all the groups are finite, I can separate them into $p$ components for each $p$. Then we can use the Littlewood–Richardson rule, which behaves quite nice algorithmically when we know two inputs and want to enumerate the third. We can also easily enumerate $(A, C)$ when $B$ is known. All these are quite well documented in the literature.
I have extended this to accommodate when $\mathbb Z$ factors may appear. But the result is quite tangled, so I would really like to confirm it in the literature. Since this looks like an elementary extension of the previous result, I expect it to be written down somewhere. Can anyone give a pointer? Alternatively it is also welcome to just directly write down the classification.
